# Adding email sent status to Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I use Excel to send monthly statements to our brokers. Is there a way to add a column to show if each of the individual email is actually sent.

Some of the rows might have an invalid email address and the only way I can tell if all of them are sent is by going through my sent folder.

```
Sub SendEmails()

    Dim answer As Variant

    answer = MsgBox("You are about to send the statements. Proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Alert")

    Select Case answer
    Case vbYes

    MsgBox "Process may take a while to finish. Do not attempt to close the worksheet or Outlook.", vbInformation, "Alert"

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Listing")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("A1:B1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Statement of Account - " & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                .Body = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Case vbNo
GoTo Quit:
    End Select

Quit:

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to keep in mind that Outlook is not able to tell if an email was actually delivered unless you have this option enabled and the recipient willingly sends you a "received" notification (which requires that the recipient's Email program supports this option). Outlook will also not be able to tell if an email address is not valid. Outlook will still try to send an email and minutes later you might get an automated reply from the destination domain that the recipient is unkown or not valid.

Comment: Thank you. I actually need an indication that the emails have been sent out from my end; I dont really bother they are delivered or not. And since I am sending the emails using vba excel, it will go through the whole list and send them so I wont be able to tell if it skips one row due to blank email cell.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just Resolve each Recipient's email before sending

eg:

```
    For Each olRecip In .Recipients
             olRecip.Resolve
        If Not olRecip.Resolve Then
             olMsg.Display
        End If
```